# I have a project where I have to print the averages in a table format however for different numbers it prints the table in two different ways

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DataAnalyze {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int i, j, k, sampleSum = 0; /* the variables that will be used */
int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE, maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; /* This     will be used to find min and max */
int[] trialAvg = new int [5];

System.out.println("Please enter the sample size: "); 
int sampleSize = input.nextInt();
long [][] arr = new long[5][sampleSize+1]; /* using long as it will be a larger size */

for(i = 0, k = 0; i < 4; sampleSum = 0, i++, k = 0) {
    System.out.println(" Enter numbers for Trial: " + (i + 1));
    /* asking user to input numbers for trials with for loop */
    for (j = 0; j < sampleSize; j++, k++) {
        System.out.println("Enter Sample # " + (k +1) + ":");
        arr[i][j]= input.nextInt();
        sampleSum += arr[i][j];
        /* the sampSum will equal arr[i][j] */
    }
     trialAvg[i] = sampleSum/sampleSize;
     System.out.println("");
     /* finding average */
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(maximum < trialAvg[i])
        maximum = trialAvg[i];

    /* testing to find min and max */

    if(minimum > trialAvg[i])
        minimum = trialAvg[i];
}
System.out.println("\tSample # \tTrial 1 \t\tTrial 2 \t\tTrial 3 \t\tTrial 4");
/* using \t to set it in table format and save it */

for ( i = 0; sampleSize < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("\t " + (i + 1) + "\t\t "  + arr[0][i] + "\t\t " + arr[1][i] + "\t\t " + arr[2][i] + "\t\t " + arr[3][i]);
}

System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
System.out.println("Average:\t\t " + trialAvg[0] + "\t\t " + trialAvg[1] + "\t\t " + trialAvg[2] + "\t\t " + trialAvg[3]);

System.out.println("Minimum Average: " + minimum);
System.out.println("Maximum Average: " + maximum);
System.out.println("");

if(maximum < (minimum*2))
    System.out.println("The trials concur with each other!");
else if (maximum == minimum)
    System.out.println("The trials match EXACTLY!");
else
    System.out.println("The trials do NOT concur!");

input.close();

}

}
```

My project is:

1. Get the sample size for each of the 4 trials

   2.reads in the data for each sample and stores them in an array (per trial)

   3.Print out data per sample in a table format 
   System.out.println("\tSample #\tTrial 1\tTrial 2\tTrial 3\tTrial 4"); // Table header line
   \t means tab character, which is used to align columns

   4.Print out the average for each case

   5.Figure out how closely the trials match with each other by

   comparing the averages using min and max

I think the problem with my code is using the long function but I am not quite sure how to fix it

When I put just one or two values it does not show the sample numbers however when I use 5 or more then it does but I can't get it to show just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the sample size: ");
    int[][] trials = new int[4][input.nextInt()];
    float[] averages = new float[trials.length];
    float min = Float.MAX_VALUE, max = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < trials.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(" Enter numbers for Trial: " + (i + 1));
        for (int j = 0; j < trials[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Sample # " + (j + 1) + ":");
            trials[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            averages[i] += trials[i][j];
        }
        averages[i] /= trials[0].length;

        if (averages[i] < min)
            min = averages[i];
        if (averages[i] > max)
            max = averages[i];
    }

    System.out.println("\tSample # \tTrial 1 \tTrial 2 \tTrial 3 \tTrial 4");

    for (int i = 0; i < trials[0].length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\t " + (i + 1) + "\t\t " + trials[0][i] + "\t\t " + trials[1][i] + "\t\t " + trials[2][i]
                + "\t\t " + trials[3][i]);
    }
    System.out.println("\t " + "average" + "\t " + averages[0] + "\t\t " + averages[1] + "\t\t " + averages[2]
            + "\t\t " + averages[3]);

    if (min == max)
        System.out.println("The trials match exactly");
    else if (max < 2 * min)
        System.out.println("The trials concur with each other");
    else
        System.out.println("The trials do not concur");

    input.close();
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it really helped, I changed mine to int as that is how they wanted it but that wasn't a huge change.